# OpenAPI Custom Generator - How do I prevent "AllOf" Class Generation in OpenApi

Tags: java, handlebars.js, mustache, openapi-generator

I'm building a custom generator to generate TypeScript/Angular models for an angular application. For a starting point, I copied the code from https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/languages/TypeScriptAngularClientCodegen.java

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent the generator from generating "AllOf" and from extending models from "AllOf" models.

The generator already generates a model with everything it needs without needing to extend from *AllOf.

I've been able to modify the .java file to prevent it from importing classes that with with "AllOf", but I can't find any documentation or examples to restrict extending from classes that end with "AllOf"

Am I missing something? It seems like there should be a way to tell the generator to just not import or create "AllOf" classes.

```js
// what I get:
import { ValidatePassword } from './validate-password.model';

export interface ChangePassword extends ChangePasswordAllOf, ValidatePassword { 
    ...
}

// what I want
import { ValidatePasswordModel } from './validate-password.model';

export interface ChangePassword extends ValidatePassword { 
    ...
}
```

---

Here's my `modelGeneric.mustache` template:

```
export interface {{classname}}{{#allOf}}{{#-first}} extends {{/-first}}{{{.}}}{{^-last}}, {{/-last}}{{/allOf}} { {{>modelGenericAdditionalProperties}}
{{#vars}}
    {{#description}}
    /**
     * {{{.}}}
     */
    {{/description}}
    {{#isReadOnly}}readonly {{/isReadOnly}}{{{name}}}{{^required}}?{{/required}}: {{#isEnum}}{{{datatypeWithEnum}}}{{/isEnum}}{{^isEnum}}{{{dataType}}}{{/isEnum}};
{{/vars}}
}{{>modelGenericEnums}}
```

Here's the relevant schema sample:

```json
...
"ChangePassword": {
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ValidatePassword"
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "required": [
        "OldPassword"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "OldPassword": {
          "title": "Current password",
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
},
...
```

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug. This PR is a workaround waiting to be merged along with references to two issues regarding the bug https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/9834

Answer (score 4):

According to this: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/3100

Could you try:

```
"ChangePassword": {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": [
        "OldPassword"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "OldPassword": {
            "title": "Current password",
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1
        }
    },
    "allOf": [{
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ValidatePassword"
    }]
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have control over the schema. I have to use what is given to me and generate the models by modifying the mustache templates and/or the generator.java file

Answer (score 0):

I think this has already been addressed in OpenAPI Generator v7.4.0. Please give it another try when you've time.

Another useful option is enabling the rule `REF_AS_PARENT_IN_ALLOF` in [OpenAPI Normalizer](https://github.com/openapitools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/customization.md#openapi-normalizer)